# Query shows greater value of duration in trace than when the query is run by itself

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, trace

The duration value in the sql server profiler trace shows a value larger for a query, than when I run the same query and take a look at the duration of execution for the query. Why is it so, or any other thing that I am missing out on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how larger? you know that in profiler the duration is stored in microseconds, right? So 1000000 means 1 second.

Besides that, you need to take into considerations other things like reuse of execution plan or even the fact that SSMS is an UI tool and may be doing something else with your query before sending it to the database, and profiler gets the statistics directly from the execution on the DB, which can explain a few seconds more on the execution

Comment: Yes, the duration in profiler is in microseconds. The exact value is 13958727, which is around 13 seconds. However, when I run the same query normally, it takes around 2-3 seconds only.

Comment: So, the next question would be, can such a large difference in the query execution times be explained on the basis of the fact that SSMS is optimizing the query?

Comment: no...like, how did you get the 13958727 values? where was the query running from? If you open SSMS, start a trace on profile and run the query on SSMS the values will be the same (or very close)

Answer (score 1):

Is the version your profiling part of an SP that is generated dynamically?

e.g.

```
..
@sql = 'select * from ' + @tablename
exec (@sql)
```

Most SPs are pre-compiled after their first execution but SPs with non-static code such as the snippet above would never become pre-compiled. But if in the query window you were running

```
select * from the_table_name
```

This might show the difference you're seeing. Bit of a guess though I'm afraid. Maybe you can tell us more about how the query is run, if it is part of an SP etc.

Comment: yes, the query I am profiling is part of a SP that is generated dynamically. Its something like this:-
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT this_.Id as Id167_1_, incomingfi1_.Id as Id164_0_ FROM BusinessObject_SourceCMEHMatchRecord this_ inner join BusinessObject_IncomingFile incomingfi1_ on this_.IncomingFile=incomingfi1_.Id WHERE incomingfi1_.SystemId = @p0 ORDER BY this_.SystemId asc;  ',N'@p0 int',@p0=1

However, when I run this query through SSMS, either the complete query (with exec sp), or only the select part (with parameters), it takes similar amount of time.

Comment: The only reason I could think of, don't know if its correct, is since the original query is fired from a web app, it may include the time to fetch the data to the web server as well, which is huge. Whereas, when run through SSMS, fetching the data might be trivial.

Comment: Ah so you're running the query directly on the server? Whilst the webapp is remote? Still if you're profiling this it shouldn't matter as your measuring how long the query takes on the server. Not sure why your query needs to be built up like that by the way as the only 'dynamic' part is the variable on the where statement.